Cannot install jdk 18.0.2.1 on macos Ventura 13.0
Currently, I am using macOS Ventura 13.0 and will develop a Java application.
So, I tried installing JDK 18.0.2.1, but I got this error message.
JDK 18.0.2.1 can't be installed on this computer.
I don't know why I cannot install JDK 18.0.2.1 on macOS Ventura 13.0
I would appreciate it if someone could help me with my problem.

Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70702494/java-errorjdk-17-0-1-can-t-be-installed-on-this-computer. Check that you have downloaded the correct version for your computer's CPU architecture (x64 vs. Arm64). Also, why on Earth would you want to install such an old, outdated version of the JDK?

Is there any type of reason you would like to install the version 18? As per
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/index.html the latest version is the 23.
You can download the latester version at: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/
You need to make sure that there is no other version of jdk installed on the computer, if you have other version that might be the reason you can not install it.
If it is your first time and you are sure you do not have another version, and you really need version 18, follow the steps at: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/install/installation-jdk-macos.html#GUID-C5F0BF25-3487-4F33-9275-7000C8E1C58C
If you followed it and still encounter issues, replicate Java error:JDK 17.0.1 can’t be installed on this computer response.

Thank you, @mauro, I was tried to install aarch64_bin JDK installer but my processor is not ARM processor, that was the reason.
